# Azure AD Claims in IdentityServer4

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I have taken this [sample from github](https://github.com/Crokus/aspnetcore-idsrv-aad-example) to attempt to use IdentityServer4 and Azure AD for authentication.

While I have it working and returning a token, it seems that the claims that I would have expected to receive from Azure AD are not included in the token(s) issued through IdentityServer.

It could be that this is intentional and that I have misunderstood this flow, but I was hoping that the roles that a user is assigned through Azure AD (plus the tenant ID and other useful 'bits' from the Azure token) would be able to be included in the tokens issued to the client.

Would anyone be able to shed some light on this for me? I can paste code in here but the link to the github code is pretty much the same as what I am using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was trying to do the same thing, and managed to eventually piece bits together from looking at the IS4 docs, Github and StackOverflow.

You need to configure a new instance of `IProfileService` ([Docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/profileservice.html)) in order to tell IdentityServer4 which additional claims for a user's identity (obtained from Azure AD in your case) you want to be passed back to the client.

An example might look like this:

```
public class CustomProfileService : IProfileService
{
  public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
  {
    // Get the 'upn' claim out from the identity token returned from Azure AD.
    var upnClaim = context.Subject.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Upn);

    // Get 'firstname' and 'givenname' claims from the identity token returned from Azure AD.
    var givenNameClaim = context.Subject.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName);
    var surNameClaim = context.Subject.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname);

    // Add the retrieved claims into the token sent from IdentityServer to the client.
    context.IssuedClaims.Add(upnClaim);
    context.IssuedClaims.Add(givenNameClaim);
    context.IssuedClaims.Add(surNameClaim);
  }

  public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
  {
      context.IsActive = true;
      return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
}
```

You will then need to register this service in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()

            // Register the new profile service. 
            .AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>();
}
```

Finally, inside of your `AccountController.cs` (within the IdentityServer4 project - I'm assuming you already have this, see [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) for a starter setup if not), you need to add the following to `ExternalLoginCallback()`:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback()
{

    //...

    // this allows us to collect any additonal claims or properties
    // for the specific protocols used and store them in the local auth cookie.
    // this is typically used to store data needed for signout from those protocols.
    var additionalLocalClaims = new List<Claim>();

    // ADD THIS LINE TO TELL IS4 TO ADD IN THE CLAIMS FROM AZURE AD OR ANOTHER EXTERNAL IDP.
    additionalLocalClaims.AddRange(claims);

    //...

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Connor - I thought I'd receive an email when a reply was posted so apologies for the late response. I believe you are correct in what you say above - but it also appears that AD uses the schema as part of the claim name, eg: 
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: FleetManager}
And at least with the above solution these can be parsed and added to the claims list. Unless there's a way for those AD claim to automagically appear in the final claims list from IdSvr4?

Comment: I realised this was left as unanswered. I think it does answer some parts of the original question and worked for @Arshath so will mark it so.